# Error 3219- Invalid Operation

Tags: ms-access, vba

I try to write a query in my Access Project but this runtime error occures in the line, where SQL query is.  This is my code:

```
Private Sub Befehl80_Click()

  Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
  Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT DISTINCT tb_KonzeptDaten.DFCC,  tb_KonzeptDaten.OBD_Code AS Konzept_Obd,tb_KonzeptDaten.DFC INTO Test_Table FROM tb_KonzeptDaten", dbOpenDynaset)

  Me.txtDs = rst.RecordCount

End Sub
```

Would you please tell me how can I solve this problem and why this error occures?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sql is an action query, it creates a table. You cannot open a recordset from an action query. If you want to run the action query, you can say:

```
Set db=CurrentDB
ssql="SELECT DISTINCT tb_KonzeptDaten.DFCC,  " _
    & "tb_KonzeptDaten.OBD_Code AS Konzept_Obd,tb_KonzeptDaten.DFC " _
    & "INTO Test_Table FROM tb_KonzeptDaten"
db.Execute ssql, dbFailOnerror

RecordsUpdated=db.RecordsAffected
```

Comment: and what should I use instead?

Comment: I have added notes on running an action query, but I am not quite sure what you want to do.

Comment: Thank you Remou , you answerd my question

Comment: Thanks so much Fionnuala!!!  I have been looking for sample code like this for about 1 week now!!!  This helps me so, so, so much!!!