# How to Pass a Parameter from an Excel Sheet into an Access Make Table Query

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm opening an ADODB connection using a small function (this works fine) and I'm trying to pass a parameter into a Make Table Query. and getting an error that reads:  'an action query can not be used as a row source'

Here is the code that I'm testing.

```
Conn.Execute (sql)

With cmd
    .ActiveConnection = Conn
    .CommandType = adCmdText
    .CommandText = "SELECT * FROM c1GetLIVEDBnTF WHERE [AS OF DATE] = ?"
End With

cmd.Parameters.Append cmd.CreateParameter("[AS OF DATE]", adInteger, adParamInput, 10)
cmd.Parameters(0).Value = Range("ASOFDATE").Value

Set rs = cmd.Execute
```

I'm trying to pass a date from Range("ASOFDATE").Value (Excel worksheet) into an Access Make Table Query.

I found the example below, but couldn't get to to work.

[Pass VBA Variable into Access Query(Excel VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38023187/pass-vba-variable-into-access-queryexcel-vba)

Comment: I'm not an expert in Access, but... If you try storing your Range("ASOFDATE").Value in a variable first and then you send the variable? I'm not sure if you can send an array as variable.

Comment: What's this piece of code: _`Conn.Execute (sql)`_  doing? Where are you getting the error?

Comment: Conn.Execute (sql) opens the DB. I run a small function to open an ADODB connection and pass in a password.  That part works fine.  I can't get the MT Query working.

Comment: `"SELECT * FROM c1GetLIVEDBnTF WHERE [AS OF DATE] = ?"` doesn't seem like a make table query to me. Which row specifically causes the error?

Comment: Is `c1GetLIVEDBnTF` a table name, or is it a query? (Perhaps that is the "Make Table" query you are mentioning?)

Comment: And is your "AS OF DATE" field really an `adInteger` type, or is it an `adDate` type?  (That's probably not causing your error though.)

Comment: Sorry for not clarifying the setup better.  The name of the MT Query is 'c1GetLIVEDBnTF' and it inserts all data into a table named 'bLIVEDBnTF'.

Comment: You can't `SELECT` from a Make Table query.  You have to make the table, then select from the table you made.  (Or change the make table query to just be a select query.)  P.S.  I don't know enough ADODB to write an answer without a lot of testing, so someone else can feel free to post a proper answer.

Comment: Replace `c1GetLIVEDBnTF` with the name of the new table.

Comment: So, wazz, the SQL should look like this?  "SELECT * FROM bLIVEDBnTF WHERE [AS OF DATE] = ?"  I guess it makes sense, but at some point I still need to fire off that Make Table Query or the whole concept doesn't work.  I'll try again when I get into my office tomorrow morning.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I finally got this to work.

```
Sub RunAccessQueries()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim ws As DAO.Workspace
Dim rst As DAO.Recordset

GoHere = ThisWorkbook.Path

ASOFDATE = Format(Range("ASOFDATE").Value, "MM/DD/YYYY")

Set ws = DBEngine.Workspaces(0)
Set db = DBEngine.OpenDatabase(GoHere & "\Main.mdb", False, False, "MS Access;PWD=pass")

sql = "INSERT INTO etc.;"
db.Execute sql, dbFailOnError
RecordsUpdated = db.RecordsAffected

db.Close

End Sub
```

The solution came form here.

[Error 3219- Invalid Operation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12260032/error-3219-invalid-operation)